# Why are ping times so long?

Tags: networking, ping

Assuming the speed of light ~ 186000 mi/sec, and the farthest from anywhere on earth you can be without leaving earth ~ 16,000 mi, that means the time it takes for light to reach any point on earth and come back <= ~172 msec. So why can ping times exceed this?

Comment: Wrong forum for this. But since you asked it's because most of the delay is due to limited processing capacity at various routers between any two points (something which makes it cost effective also).

Comment: I agree it is off topic for SO, but it would fit in on SU I think.

Answer (score 6):

A few reasons

1. Your assumption about speed is wrong, electronic communications through a wire travel [is about 2/3 the speed of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_propagation_speed).
2. You are not traveling a strait line from Point A to Point B, so it could be longer.
3. Your assumption about leaving earth is wrong, satellite links can often be used for intercontinental network links
4. (the biggest culprit) You need to pass through many computers (run the program `tracert` and you can see), the computer does not instantainouly forward the packet on from the time it received to to the time it sends it to the next person. If the computer doing the forwarding is under a very heavy load it could take a while for the packet to be forwarded on while it sits in a queue waiting to be processed.

Comment: Furthermore, there may be overhead at both endpoints. On the responding side, the node may have to decide whether it actually wants to answer the ping request. On the requesting side, the node may spend a bit of time processing the ping response (in the host operating system) before it figures out which request the response belongs to; although the payload of the ping/pong conversation is often a timestamp, in order to mitigate this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is a completely wrong comparison. for some reasons:

1. Electrons are involved in the pinging not light. So you can't compare light to electrons. Thats wrong.
2. Servers that your ping request `hop`s on them are not processing them in zero sec. It actually takes time to process the ping packet and send it where it's supposed to go.
3. Your link to the internet is not a direct link. You have to pass through a DNS server (If you ran ping with a hostname not an IP), many routers and different types of links(satellite, wired, fiber optic). So it's not like emitting from this side of planet to the another side

Comment: I can not understand why you guys down-vote.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I guess it's because "pass through lots of DNS servers" is just plain wrong.

Comment: Thx for the response but what is wrong about it?

Comment: the dns response time has nothing to do with your ping time. It resolves the DNS to the IP then it performs the ping. (I did not downvote either btw)

Comment: OK I see I assumed he may have ran ping on a hostname not on an IP. That way doesn't it affect the ping time?

Comment: When doing a ping, you do only one DNS query. But I can understand what you said; it's in line with Scott's answer. What nobody pointed out yet is that iCMP is the lowest priority protocol for a router (at least the ECHO subprotocol, specifically). When it is under heavy load, the router will promptly discard or delay packets of ICMP ECHO requests.

Comment: Thx @GuiAmbros for mentioning out that fact. I edited my answer and corrected it. :)

Comment: Also, the electrons in an electric current flow very slowly, in the order of millimeters per hour, nowhere near the speed of light. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity

Comment: @Joni thats my reason #1 in the answer.

Comment: I don't think you understand. The speed of an electric *signal* has nothing to do with how fast electrons move.

Comment: @Joni I went really low-level in my answer. I only meant ping is not light. so it can not be in the speed of light. And please don't offense me with saying you don't understand. After working 4 years in the field of designing PCB and electrical engineering that's offensive for me. thx

Comment: @Joni I admit my #1 is a little bit wrong. I think you guys understand different from my sentence. I will edit my answer to be more exact and correct.

Comment: I meant you didn't understand my argument. I didn't mean to offend. The answer looks better now.